# Can i use F4map for commercial uses

Tags: 3d, maps, openstreetmap, licensing

I am looking for a 3D maps under OSM. So far i have founded that the best maps available is F4map http://demo.f4map.com/

As i can see also it's distributed under the CC-By-NC licence, that offers share and update. Can i use it for commercial uses and where can i founded the source code. Otherwise if there any other maps that offer the same functionalities.

Comment: This question should be in [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). StaclOverflow is not the correct place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F4map is proprietary, the source code is not available. For more information see https://www.f4map.com/#goto_contact. Not sure where you read about a CC-By-NC license.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other 3D maps that i can use with same functionalities ?

Comment: F4map is the most advanced 3D map based on OSM data as far as I know. For other solutions take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D_development.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on F4map, and a commercial license should be available this year.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, can you provide more details please ? I already send you an e-mail but still no answer !

Comment: @HamzaRhaiem sorry, all I know is that something should be available this year...